# Vertically aligning text, non-standard situation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a CSS counter and pseudo-elements to customize ordered list numbers - 
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RZTQW/)

What I'd like to achieve, is aligning a text vertically within a `<li>` element whenever it's a single line, otherwise keep it aligned to top as is.

Here's a preview of how I want it to look like - http://cl.ly/image/2f1U1p0k2M14

Any solutions (even involving JS/jQuery) would be much appreciated.

Comment: align vertically how exactly ?

Comment: like [this](http://cl.ly/image/2f1U1p0k2M14)

Comment: It is possible, but not as easily as you might think. The text naturally overflows based on the width of the viewport, so you have to calculate wether or not the text is overflowing, which is not an easy task, and then set the appropriate style. Unless someone has a clever CSS workaround ?

Comment: A solution with jQuery may be possible if you are willing to wrap the content of you `li` element in a separate block element.  The absolutely positioned counter element is making difficult to distinguish between a 1 and 2 lines of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Javascript (jQuery) to check the height of **each** `li` element.

If its [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) is euqal to `font-size * line-hight` then add class "single-line"`, if it is greater then add class "multi-line".

In your CSS you can set the classes and their respective vertical-aling value.

Or for using a little less code, you make one the "default" and only add a class if it is different.

PS: Thanks to @Marc Audet's comment here is an addition.
If you use a `min-height` then you have to ensure that your font-size and line-height values are high enough so that a double line entry is at least 1px higher than the `min-height` value!

Comment: This definitely does the trick in this particular situation - http://jsfiddle.net/RZTQW/1/. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: This does not work properly if a `li` element creates two lines of text.

Comment: @Marc Audet: Yes, you are right. Tigran has to increase the `line-height` by 1px! A double line entry has to be minimum 1px higher than the `min-height` value. Then it works!

Comment: Yup. In my particular case line-height is explicitly set to 18px, so checking if `height < 36` will work. Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RZTQW/2/

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the design is rather inconsistent. There would be no way of telling without javascript and even this would only work onload. If the user increased the font size via the browser you would run into another bunch of problems as you can't detect when they do that.